# how to run Jquery Click function on ng-click in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on a mobile app where I am using MDL for app UI and Angualr js
I bought the theme from themeforest named "FAB".
I am using angular js to show the data from server using API's where I am displaying all the products which is coming from server.I want to run Add to  Cart section on the page which has some in-built jquery applied to it. if I dont write Angualr js then my Jquery is working fine.
here is the link of my Page without Angular js 
 [Link without Angular js](http://ilexsquare.com/Demo/producttest.html) ,
 [link with angualr js](http://ilexsquare.com/Demo/product.html)

I am new to angular js .. so it is something which is blocking jquery click event

Comment: To get the help you need, I recommend that you try to isolate the problem and post the relevant code.

Comment: is your jquery script not loading before your angular script?

Comment: yes my jquery is loading before Angular script

Comment: I am new to angular js .. so it is something which is blocking jquery click event

Answer (score 0):

While I'm creating plunker for the answer, I ran into the same problem.
But, It was solved by inserting `app.js` before `</body>` tag. I think it might be related with angular's inside operation.

Here are different plunkers([app.js in head](http://plnkr.co/edit/C8VQjMcUBhh70WVccQ9J?p=preview), [app.js in body](http://plnkr.co/edit/rx2PbPkmRoaJMAeuAVST?p=preview))